# Динамические данные на php (или wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cms

У меня есть большое количество страниц (предположим, 150), с некоторым количеством статики на странице (страницы - описание товара). Но что делать в том случае, если нужно добавить одинаковый текст на все страницы? Допустим, какое-то замечание. Как реализовать это лучше всего, кроме варианта копипастить замечание на каждую страницу?

Comment: Добавить этот текст в шаблон страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть редактор кода шаблона. Перейдите в него, найдите вид полной страницы и в нужное место вставьте ваш текст. Тем самым текст, будет на всех страницах с товарами

Comment: У всех товаров один шаблон, как сказали выше, можно найти его в редакторе админ-панели и добавить в нужное место текст.